# Sequence requests Restkit 0.20

Tags: ios, session, restkit, afnetworking, restkit-0.20

**The environment:
- MyViewController (same ViewController)**

Using the `RKObjectManager` reference to the `AFHTTPClient` (`* client`).

**1 - First request**

```
[client setDefaultHeader:@"api_key" value:session.getApi_Key];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Length" value:postLength];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"signature" value:signature];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"date" value:date];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:nil
                                       path:[SMRequestFactory getTokenRequestPath]
                                 parameters:[SMRequestFactory getTokenRequestParams: self.usuario.text : self.senha.text]
                                    success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) { **Call request 2** }
                                    failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {...}];
```

**2 - Second request**

```
[client setDefaultHeader:@"api_key" value:session.getApi_Key];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"access_token" value:session.getAccessToken];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"signature" value:session.getSignature];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"date" value:session.getData];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:nil
                                       path:[SMRequestFactory getLoginRequestPath]
                                 parameters:[SMRequestFactory getLoginRequestParams]
                                    success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) { **Call request 3** }
                                    failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {...}];
```

**3 - Third request   Operation time out**

```
[client setDefaultHeader:@"api_key" value:session.getApi_Key];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"access_token" value:session.getAccessToken];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"signature" value:session.getSignature];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"date" value:session.getData];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:[SMRequestFactory getUsuariosRequestPath]
                                       parameters:nil
                                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){ }
                                          failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {}];
```

If follow the sequence, the third request: The server receive and respond but 60 seconds later occurs the timeout.

Even called by buttons (not from success before) the third request got the timeout if follow the sequence.

When called by first the Third request works.

Comment: Have you checked the server logs? What is the session - in particular the date that is being set in the headers? Are any other requests being made concurrently (which could alter the common headers)? You need to be clear on what the server expects to receive in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "sequencing/chaining" your request in the success code block, maybe try calling it via GCD async dispatch?

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    // Call next request
});
```

http://jeffreysambells.com/2013/03/01/asynchronous-operations-in-ios-with-grand-central-dispatch

Comment: I belive that the restkit api maybe have something to do this.

Comment: Yes it probably is, maybe work around it? Generally it's a good idea to string your requests asynchronously.

Comment: The code in the question will be asynchronous. GCD isn't required, RestKit uses `NSOperationQueue` internally.

Comment: Ok Wain. But about thhe third request and the timeout?